# Modified array of object with value from a given object TS/JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

Guys what is the best approach to modified array of object with value from object. E.g: lets say that we have array and object like this:

```
let arr = [
{
        parameter: 'aaa', 
        isSomething: false
},
{
        parameter: 'bbb', 
        isSomething: false
}, 
{
        parameter: 'ccc', 
        isSomething: false
}
];

let obj = {aaa: false, bbb: true, ccc: true}
```

and output that I want to achieve is:

```
let arr = [
{
        parameter: 'aaa', 
        isSomething: false
},
{
        parameter: 'bbb', 
        isSomething: true
}, 
{
        parameter: 'ccc', 
        isSomething: true
}
];
```

Could you help me with this one? I would be grateful. Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of the first array? It seems like you just want to create an array based on the `entries` of `obj` - I don't understand what you need the first array for

Comment: Have you tried using a simple for loop? Something like `arr.forEach(item => item.isSomething = obj[item.parameter])` should work

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Arra#map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) combined with [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Code:

```js
const arr = [{parameter: 'aaa',isSomething: false},{parameter: 'bbb',isSomething: false},{parameter: 'ccc',isSomething: false}]

const obj = {
  aaa: false,
  bbb: true,
  ccc: true
}

const result = arr.map(({ parameter, isSomething }) => ({ 
  parameter, 
  isSomething: obj[parameter]
}))

console.log(result)
```